# How to generate each day of backlog for a ticket

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Hi I'm trying to create a procedure for calculating the backlog for each day.

For example: I have a ticket with `ticket_submitdate` on 12-sep-2015 and `resolved_date` on 15-sep-2015 in one table. This ticket should come as a backlog in the `backlog_table` because it was not resolved on the same day as the `ticket_submitdate`.

I have another column `date_col` in the `backlog_table` where the date on which the ticket was a backlog is displayed,i.e, it should be there in the `ticket_backlog` table for dates 13-sep-2015 and 14-sep-2015 and the `date_col` column should have this ticket for both these dates.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some test data:

```
create table backlog (ticket_no number, submit_date date, resolved_date date);

insert into backlog values (100, date '2015-09-12', date '2015-09-15');
insert into backlog values (200, date '2015-09-12', date '2015-09-14');
insert into backlog values (300, date '2015-09-13', date '2015-09-15');
insert into backlog values (400, date '2015-09-13', date '2015-09-16');
insert into backlog values (500, date '2015-09-13', date '2015-09-13');
```

This query generates a list of dates which spans the range of BACKLOG records, and joins them to the BACKLOG.

```
with dt as ( select min(submit_date) as st_dt
                   , greatest(max(resolved_date), max(submit_date)) as end_dt
            from backlog)
    , dt_range as ( select st_dt + (level-1) as date_col
                    from dt
                    connect by level <= ( end_dt - st_dt ))
select b.ticket_no
       , d.date_col
from backlog b
     cross join dt_range d
where d.date_col between b.submit_date and b.resolved_date
and b.submit_date != b.resolved_date
order by b.ticket_no
       , d.date_col
/
```

Therefore it produces a list of TICKET_NOs with all the dates when they are live:

```
 TICKET_NO DATE_COL
---------- ---------
       100 12-SEP-15
       100 13-SEP-15
       100 14-SEP-15
       100 15-SEP-15
       200 12-SEP-15
       200 13-SEP-15
       200 14-SEP-15
       300 13-SEP-15
       300 14-SEP-15
       300 15-SEP-15
       400 13-SEP-15
       400 14-SEP-15
       400 15-SEP-15

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

The result set does not include ticket #500 because it was resolved on the day of submission.  You will probably need to tweak the filters to fit your actual business rules.

Comment: Hi APC,

I have a ticket table with ticketsubmitdate and the resolved date present. i have to insert the ticket details from this table to the backlog table. I want the result exactly how it is displayed using your select  query. how do i insert in that table. the date_col is present in the backlog table.

Comment: You should be able to figure it from what I've given you.  But if you need further help please edit your question, to post some sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure I understood your question, if you are looking for all dates between two date range then you can use below query -

```
select trunc(date_col2+lv) from
  (select level lv from dual connect by level < (date_col1-date_col2-1) )
order by 1
```